# Get "iPhone 3.0" for the base SDK in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, base-sdk

I just finish my iPhone game using cocos2d, and I want to submit it to Apple.

I've read this article: [Building Your App for Distribution](http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/build.html), and they say:

> 4 If necessary, adjust the base SDK for the device you want to deploy to. (e.g. iPhone Device 3.0, or whatever minimum version you want to build for.)

I want to put "iPhone 3.0" for the minimum version, but in Xcode I have only the choice of "iPhone 3.2"...
Where and how can I get the iPhone 3.0 for Xcode? (I have Xcode  3.2.3)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your target settings, look for "iPhone OS Deployment Target", and select 3.0 there. You can keep 3.2 as your build SDK, as long as you don't use any 3.2-specific stuff. If you want to build against 3.0, make sure the base SDK is set properly in your target and project settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My goal is to make my game work with all the iPhone 3.0+. And I can't find the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" that you are talking about...

Comment: Right-click on your target, select "Get info", select the "Build" tab, and type "Deployment" in the search field.